# How to access data inside a html response of ajax

Tags: jquery

I am returning text/html from server side: `<img title="Hello World">`. My intent is to retrieve that title in ajax success callback function (I am using jquery form plugin):

```
options_ie['success'] = function(data,statusText,xhr,form) {
    // How can I get title from "data"? 
}
```

I cannot return json because IE<10 treat json response as a file download. For FF and Chrome I simply return json and manipulate the data with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr) for this,
like,

```
options_ie['success'] = function(data,statusText,xhr,form) {
    console.log($(data).find('img').attr('title'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.get('/myurl',function(html){
       $("#target").html(html);
       var title = $("#target img").attr("title");
    });
```

if you want to use JSON, just use `$.getJSON(..)`, It works in IE << 10

Answer (score 0):

You can get title attribute like this.

```
options_ie['success'] = function(data,statusText,xhr,form) {
    var imgTitle = $(data).attr('title');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply adding this before manipulate `data`:

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
```